# How to open a new activity on click of items in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am a newbie in android development and as expected finding some difficulties with navigation drawer, I want to open a new activity by clicking the items that appear in left pane of navigation drawer.

i.e if the click the items appear in navigation drawer it should open a new activity.

I have tried the following but have no idea regarding the same

```
package com.example.demo_data1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class NavDrawer extends Activity {
   String[] menu;
   DrawerLayout dLayout;
   ListView dList;
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.third_page);
    menu = new String[]{"Home","Android","Windows","Linux","Raspberry Pi","WordPress","Videos","Contact Us"};
      dLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
      dList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
      adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menu);
      dList.setAdapter(adapter);
      dList.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);
      dList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
      dLayout.closeDrawers();
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putString("Menu", menu[position]);
    }        
      });
 } 
}
```

So please anyone that can help me with the solution will be really appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? You have your onItemClick method, why don't you put your code in there?

Comment: Go for the "https://www.codeofaninja.com/2014/02/android-navigation-drawer-example.html". you will find step by step procedure and explanation for navigation drawer

Comment: the problem is i want to open different activities on click of different items can you please help me with the neccessary logic, i have not much idea about android programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your `onItemClick()` method should be defined as

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
  dLayout.closeDrawers();
  Bundle args = new Bundle();
  args.putString("Menu", menu[position]);
  Intent i = new Intent(NavDrawer.this, SecondActivity.class);
  switch(position){
      case 0:
         i = new Intent(NavDrawer.this, Activity1.class);
         break;
      case 1:
         i = new Intent(NavDrawer.this, Activity2.class);
         break;
         ...
         ...
  }
  i.putExtra(args);
  startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for quick reply but if i want to open different activities on different item click what the procedure will be?? sorry for the trouble bt seriously i have no idea regarding the same.

Comment: you can use a `switch`-`case` block and use the `position` variable to start different activities. see edited answer

Comment: thanks for the solution just a small help again when new activity starts it should also display same navigation drawer as in the main activity.

Comment: Done with the upvoting , please help me with an update

Comment: The answer to your question is that **IT DEPENDS**. If your boss or project manager tells you that second activity must also have navigation drawer, then do that. But if I were you, I would put navigation drawer only in first activity.

Comment: but my requirement is also to view the drawers in all activities

Comment: sure, then put the same navigation drawer in all activities, no problem :)

Comment: but when i do so the application stops saying unfortunately stopped

Comment: ha ha well ... this is a new error, a different problem! Welcome to Android, I would say :) .... but seriously, you should post this as a new question with code and logcat error, then send me a comment here, I will take a look at the new question :)

Comment: hey take a look at this link    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738288/how-to-add-subitems-in-a-navigation-drawer/28738612#28738612  want help in this too

Comment: where is the new question ??

Comment: check out the link above its a different topic