# How to add subitems in a Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, expandablelistview, navigation-drawer

I want to add subitems in my navigation drawer but i am not able to execute it because i have no idea about the logic , i have tried some examples but i am able to display only the items.

i have tried the following code :

```
package com.example.demo_data1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class NavDrawer extends Activity {
   String[] menu;
   DrawerLayout dLayout;
   ListView dList;
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.third_page);
    menu = new String[]{"Home","Android","Windows","Linux","Raspberry Pi","WordPress","Videos","Contact Us"};
      dLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
      dList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
      adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menu);
      dList.setAdapter(adapter);
      dList.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);
      dList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
      dLayout.closeDrawers();
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putString("Menu", menu[position]);
      Intent i = new Intent(NavDrawer.this, NavDrawer.class);
      switch(position){
      case 0:
         i = new Intent(NavDrawer.this, MainActivity.class);
         break;
      case 1:
         i = new Intent(NavDrawer.this, Retrieve.class);
         break;
  }
  i.putExtra(null, args);
  startActivity(i);
    }        
      });
  } 
 }
```

Below is the xml layout:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

<ListView android:id="@+id/drawerList"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#fff"></ListView>

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I just want to add subitems to its respective item and the subitems should display on the right side of its parent.

So please anyone can help me with this m a bit new to android,

Thanks and regards.

Comment: where is the XML of your `DrawerLayout` ? and what is error ?

Comment: theres no error i just want to add subitems of the respected items in the listview which i am unable to implement do u have any idea regarding the same.

Comment: post XML of activity layout

Comment: i shall be sure to look at this ... give me a little time as I am occupied with another problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can add views to drawer in the xml. Try this:

```
<!-- Main layout -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Place your main screen items here -->
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Main" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Slider menu -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menuDrawer"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@color/app_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btButton1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btButton2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/elvItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use Expandable listview in Drawer** 
Below is an example

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
        ExpandableListView expListView;
        List<String> listDataHeader;
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // get the listview
            expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

            // preparing list data
            prepareListData();

            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

            // setting list adapter
            expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            // Listview Group click listener
            expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            // Listview Group expanded listener
            expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            // Listview Group collasped listener
            expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

            // Listview on child click listener
            expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                    + " : "
                                    + listDataChild.get(
                                               listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                            childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

        /*
         * Preparing the list data
         */
        private void prepareListData() {
            listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
            listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

            // Adding child data
            listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
            listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
            listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

            // Adding child data
            List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
            top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
            top250.add("The Godfather");
            top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
            top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
            top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
            top250.add("The Dark Knight");
            top250.add("12 Angry Men");

            List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
            nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
            nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
            nowShowing.add("Turbo");
            nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
            nowShowing.add("Red 2");
            nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

            List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
            comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
            comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
            comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
            comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
            comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
        }}
```

**Adapter**

```
    public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private Context _context;
        private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
        // child data in format of header title, child title
        private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

        public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context,
                List<String> listDataHeader,
                HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
            this._context = context;
            this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
            this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(
                    this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                    childPosititon);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition,
                final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition,
                    childPosition);

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,
                        null);
            }

            TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

            txtListChild.setText(childText);
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(
                    this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return this._listDataHeader.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group,
                        null);
            }

            TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
            lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition,
                int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: hey sagar thank you for quick reply can you help me with the layout for the same